# Problema al registrar set item

Tags: javascript, frontend

como están? Estoy teniendo un problema al momento de querer registrar el setitem. nose que puede ser que este haciendo mal. Agradezco su ayuda!`const registrarPago = document.getElementById("continuar").addEventListener("click", () => { sessionStorage.setItem("prueba1") })`

Comment: Mencionaste dos veces que hay un problema, pero no mencionás el error en cuestión. Pulsá en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta. Leé [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

setItem recibe 2 parametros `setItem(nombre, valor)` solo estas enviando 1

Tu codigo deveria ser

`window.sessionStorage.setItem('mivariable', 12343)`

Comment: muchas gracias ahi me funcionó